# Проблема с отправкой переменной через Ajax в контроллер Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Я новичок, с Ajax не работал, но передо мной встала задача реализовать систему оценки новостей через Ajax. Естественно начал с простого, хотел поставить обычный счётчик, однако столкнулся с проблемой отправки данных через Ajax.

Суть идеи заключается в том, что контроллеру нужно передать последний сегмент url, по которому контроллер должен найти в базе данных нужное значение для конкретной новости. Для этого в обработчике добавил код, который задаёт это значение переменной. Но при её передаче консоль выдает ошибки:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>
> at JSON.parse ()
>
> at Function.n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
>
> at Object.success (news-5:44)
>
> at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> at y (jquery.min.js:4)
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)

Данный не отправляются, срабатывает проверка отправки данных и на странице появляется значение "Данные не отправлены". Где сидит ошибка?

Ajax:

```
<script>

  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#likes").click(
      function(){
        var slug = location.href.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
        console.log(slug);
        sendAjaxForm('likes', 'likes', '/likes/like/', slug);
        return false; 
      }
    );
  });

  function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url, slug) {
    console.log(slug);
      $.ajax({
          url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
          type:     "POST", //метод отправки
          dataType: "text", //формат данных
          data: slug,  // объект
          success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
            result = $.parseJSON(response);
            $('#likes').html(result.likes);
        },
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
              $('#likes').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
        }
    });
  }


</script>
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php 

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script asses allowed');

class Likes extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function like() {
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
        $this->data['news'] = $this->news_model->getNews($slug);
        $count = $this->data['news']['likes'] + 1;
        $this->news_model->updateLikes($slug, $count);
        if($this->news_model->updateLikes($slug, $count)){
            $response = array(
                'html' => true,
                'count' => $count
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Метод в модели:

```
public function updateLikes($slug, $count) {

    $data = array(
        'slug' => $slug,
        'likes' => $count
    );

    return $this->db->update('news', $data, array('slug' => $slug));
}
```

Comment: Неужели так сложно посмотреть что приходит от сервера, и насколько это соответствует ожиданиям?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, контроллер возвращал пустоту